# How should I modify my routes for protected routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

const isAuthenticated, AuthenticatedRoute is my sample codes for protected Routes,

I want to apply them to my routes below.
It seems like, I have to modify my routes props or const AuthenticatedRoute but I'm in stuck...

Please help me to solve this problem.

ex) want to apply my codes something like this.

```
 <Route path="/"  render={props => <TheLayout {...props}/>} />

-->   <AuthenticatedRoute path="/"  render={props => <TheLayout {...props}/>} />
```

Here is my Routes(App.tsx)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
...
...

const isAuthenticated = () => {
  //Write some condition
  return true;
}

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component, ...rest } : isAny ) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    isAuthenticated()
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
);

...
...
...
const TheLayout : any = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/TheLayout'));
const Login :any = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/login/Login'));500'));

class App extends Component  {

  render() {
    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />
                <Route path="/"  render={props => <TheLayout {...props}/>} />
              </Switch>
            </React.Suspense>
        </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://dev.to/pprathameshmore/protected-routes-in-react-js-216i